# FaceRecognizer with openCV

Tags: java

I am using openCV 2.4.9 Java Library and I have several problems to implement some FaceRecognizer. I know that, in C++, the class `contrib.FaceRecognizer` is Abastract, but I don't know if it also happens to the Java Library (actually the Java Documentation is too much scarce!). Anyways, here are my tries to call the class:

`FaceRecognizer rec = new FaceRecognizer();`
or
`FaceRecognizer rec = null;`
or
`FaceRecognizer rec;`

And finally, I'm trying to call the `Train` and `Predict` methods this ways:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    FaceRecognizer rec = null;
    List<Mat> images;
    images = new ArrayList<Mat>();
    images.add(Highgui.imread("/home/adriano/Desktop/fotos/gabi/1.jpg"));
    images.add(Highgui.imread("/home/adriano/Desktop/fotos/gabi/2.jpg"));
    images.add(Highgui.imread("/home/adriano/Desktop/fotos/gabi/3.jpg"));
    images.add(Highgui.imread("/home/adriano/Desktop/fotos/estevao/1.jpg"));
    images.add(Highgui.imread("/home/adriano/Desktop/fotos/estevao/2.jpg"));
    images.add(Highgui.imread("/home/adriano/Desktop/fotos/estevao/3.jpg"));

    Mat labels = new Mat(1, 6, CvType.CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));
    // How can I add some values different from 0 to this Mat?


    rec.train(images, labels);


    // Predicts the label
    System.out.println(testando.predict(Highgui.imread("/home/adriano/Desktop/fotos/gabi/4.jpg"));


    }
```

Any help is welcome  (:

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/34342/missing-createfisherfacerecognizer-method-on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make facerecognizer you can use

```
FaceRecognizer rec=createLBPHFaceRecognizer();
```

or

```
FaceRecognizer rec=createEigenFaceRecognizer();
```

or

```
FaceRecognizer rec=createFisherFaceRecognizer();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since OpenCV v3.0, the way to create `FaceRecognizer` is, e.g.:

```
faceRecognizer = LBPHFaceRecognizer.create();
```

The same way you can create the two other recognizers.